# Интерфейс IDisposable в C#

Tags: c#

Что такое интерфейс IDisposable, зачем он нужен и как его реализовать?
Как в методе  Dispose освобождать занятые ресурсы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно IDisposable используют в тех случаях, когда автоматическая сборка мусора не работает. Например, если используется доступ к нативным ресурсам через P/Invoke.

```
public sealed class Handle : IDisposable {
    private GCHandle gch;

    public Handle(Object o) {
        this.gch = GCHandle.Alloc(o);
    }

    private void Close() {
        if (this.gch.IsAllocated) {
            this.gch.Free();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        this.Close();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~Handle() {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

интерфейс IDisposable используется совместно с конструкцией **using**
например:

```
using(var myObject=new MyObject())
{
   //тут какая-нибудь реализация
}
```

после выхода этого блока у объекта **myObject** вызывается метод Dispose()